# Pass outer recognizers if inner didn't receive the touch

Tags: ios, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view and there's a circle programmatically drawn on it. Also I have a gesture recognizer which delegate checks if it should receive touch (it should if the tap was made on this circle).

```objective-c
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    circleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleHighlighted:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:circleTapRecognizer];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    CGPoint hit = [touch locationInView:self];

    if (gestureRecognizer == circleTapRecognizer) {
        BOOL hitsCircle = hit.x >= CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds) - self.circleRadius &&
                          hit.x <= CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds) + self.circleRadius &&
                          hit.y >= CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds) - self.circleRadius &&
                          hit.y <= CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds) + self.circleRadius;

        return hitsCircle;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

But I want the superview to receive the touch if the tap was made on space out of this circle. How can I do this? For sure, I can make a delegate method call named `tappedNotOnCircle` which will call superview's logic, but I wonder if there is an easier way.

Comment: Glad to see that you've chosen version without GestureRecognizer. Keep things simple. :) Could you answer why have you changed your mind? (Just for my interest)

Comment: @MarkKryzhanouski Because the gesture recognizer didn't work. At one moment when method in the topic returned `NO`, recognizers of the underlying views didn't call and nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the solution without GestureRecognizer. Just override **-(BOOL)[UIView pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event]**.

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    BOOL hitsCircle = hit.x >= CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds) - self.circleRadius &&
                      hit.x <= CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds) + self.circleRadius &&
                      hit.y >= CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds) - self.circleRadius &&
                      hit.y <= CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds) + self.circleRadius;

    return hitsCircle;
}
```

For better understanding please refer to Apple docs [Defining a Custom View](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW23)